# Azure Bot Services templates - botFilePath / botFileSecret fields are missing (Node.js / SDK v4

Tags: botframework

After using the Azure templates for Basic and Echo bot (Node.js SDK v4) the resources are created and testing the bots via the online WebChat in the Azure portal works fine.

In the application settings, however, the botFilePath and botFileSecret are not visible (only MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassWord). After downloading the source code, I noticed that the .env file is created with MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassWord.

Any thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`botFilePath` and `botFileSecret` aren't included because the newer Echo and Basic bots don't have `.bot` files. We're moving away from using them in all BotBuilder SDKs. It will take some time for all of the samples, documentation, and emulator to reflect this. All secrets and settings should be stored in `.env` (Node) or `appsettings.json` (C#).

If you need to test your downloaded bot with the Emulator (for now):

1. Open Emulator (note: you likely need the [latest version](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases))
2. Click Open Bot

[image]

3. Add the bot URL (usually `http://localhost:3978/api/messages`) and click Connect
   [image]

Note: Leave App ID and App password blank and remove it from your `.env` file for local testing. Be sure it's in your App Settings when deploying (it should stay there, by default, when you re-deploy/publish).

Comment: Thanks. that approach makes sense to me. What would be the best medium to stay on track with developments like these?

Comment: No problem. Unfortunately, a lot of the higher-level changes like this aren't made public until release. We make [fairly detailed release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/releases), though. For smaller stuff, you can track what's coming in the [BotBuilder-JS Issues](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc) and [BotBuilder Issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc). Just look for issues that are tagged for the next release version (4.4 now).